# file browser dialog implementation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have seen that there is a folderBrowserDialog but couldn't see one for files .

I should implement one myself or there is something built in ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class.

Answer (score 7):

You want the [`OpenFileDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

> This class allows you to check whether a file exists and to open it

Answer (score 6):

There is [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) which gives you a file chooser that looks something like this:

[image: OpenFileDialog]
<sub>(source: [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/1595/Images/OpenFileDlgImg1.jpg))</sub>