# How to create a Textbox to save a path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I've seen a lot of times, programas that have something like `textbox` that is used to get/save the `path` of something... There's a button on it and when you click on it opens a prompt for you to select the directory, you know ? 
How Could I do that?
I have to read a `file.txt`, and I need my application to open this `file.txt`, how I open this "prompt" ? Then I need to save a `destination path` the same way... Is it actually a `textbox`or something else?

Thanks

Comment: A button click... But in the others programs it seems it's inside the box you know ? But I think Slaks is right, its just too close to the textbox...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308202/file-browser-dialog-implementation

Comment: Thanks @BojanKomazec im reading it now... [off] Why The DownVotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `OpenFileDialog` to your form ([MSDN has more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx))

This sample should explain it better than I could!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is this `openFileDialog1.FilterIndex` ? and what if I want only the path of the directory and not a name of a file ?

Comment: Filter index just specifies which filter to default to - it can be left out. If you only want a folder then you would use the folder browser dialog (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a button next to the textbox.

In the button's Click event handler, create and show a `SaveFileDialog`, then assign its result to the textbox's text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenFileDialog

```
string path;
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = file.FileName;
}
```

Now the file path is saved to the string, and you can then manipulate the file.

Comment: What if I want only the path of the directory and not a name of a file ?

Comment: I believe this gives you the path, correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: NeverMind... TO get the path of the directory instead of the file itself, I just need to use `FolderBrowserDialog` xD Thanks !